# help on understanding logic

Tags: c++

How can I logically understand this:

```
int low_digit = value % 10;
value /= 10;
```

Where I am lost is when mod divides and print the remainder. What is it dividing by?

What does `value /= 10;` mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/=` is the C++ way of saying:

```
value = value / 10;
```

Here `value % 10` gives you the reminder of dividing it by 10. Imagine `value` is 19, this will give you 9, the last digit (reminder of dividing it by 10). The last statement, will divide that value by 10 (integer division), and will give you 1 (the tens digit).

Comment: so if id want to input <145> and print largest digit..(5)..what would be a good technique..using the %

Comment: For 145, you mean the least digit, right? Again using `value % 10` will give you 5.

Answer (score 2):

This is an assignment shorthand and a more efficient way of saying:

```
value = value / 10;
```

Just like:

```
i++;
```

is:

```
i = i + 1;
```

or:

```
i +=1;
```

You could also do:

```
value %= 10; // same as value = value % 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/*int low_digit =*/ value % 10;
/*value /= 10; */
```

First, `value modulo 10` is calculated.  This divides `value` by `10`, and the result is the remainder of the division.

```
int low_digit = value % 10;
/*value /= 10; */
```

Then an `int` is created, named `low_digit`, and assigned the value from the modulo operation.

```
/*int low_digit = value % 10;*/
value /= 10;
```

Finally, `value` is divided by `10`, and assigned to the result.  This is the same as `value = value / 10;`
The result of this entire sequence is to remove the least-significant-digit from `value`, and place it into `low_digit`

Answer (score 1):

It's shorthand for and works with all arithmetic operations:

```
value = value / 10:
```

Answer (score 1):

`value % 10` gives the reminder of the division. For example `345 % 10` is equal to `5`.

`value /= 10;` means the same thing as `value = value / 10;`

Answer (score 1):

`value /= 10` means that you divide `value` by `10` and you assign the result back to the variable `value`.

Answer (score 0):

`/=` is a division assignment operator.

source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Compound_assignment_operators)

Answer (score 0):

When you divide by a modulus you will receive the remainder.  Ex: 10 % 3 = 1.

While when you divide by a regular division symbol with an int (non-double data type), you will receive the "number of times a number goes into another number."  Ex: 10 / 3 = 3, hence 3 goes into 10, 3 times (think long division in school).

In your particular example you are pretty much inputting a number, storing the least significant number in a variable, then returning the number without the least significant digit.  Example:

If value = 12, then low_digit = 2 (12 % 10 = 2), and value is updated to 1 (12 / 10 = 1).